# page reloads automatically after a jquery

Tags: jquery, refresh

I have a jquery function that asks a question but when a user clicks on submit, regardless if the answer is correct or not, it will automatically refresh the page on its own. My objective is when a user drags an icon on the corresponding droppable div, it will show the answer which is working fine, but when the user answers the question, it will refresh the page. Please help. Here is the website if the snippets is not working. http://ceruleanlab.com/prozzleRaw/prozzle.php

```js
function dragItem_ts() {
  $(function() {
    $("#draggable_ts, #draggable-nonvalid").draggable();
    $("#droppable_ts").droppable({
      accept: "#draggable_ts",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        showquiz();
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").find("p").html("Correct!").alert("I am  an alert  box!");
      }
    });
  });
}

function dragItem_email() {
  $(function() {
    $("#draggable_email, #draggable-nonvalid").draggable();
    $("#droppable_email").droppable({
      accept: "#draggable_email",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        showquiz2();
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").find("p").html("Correct!");
      }
    });
  });
}


function dragItem_validation() {
  $(function() {
    $("#draggable_validation, #draggable-nonvalid").draggable();
    $("#droppable_validation").droppable({
      accept: "#draggable_validation",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        showquiz3();
        $(this)
          .addClass("ui-state-highlight").find("p").html("Correct!");
      }
    });
  });

}

function dragItem_availability() {
  $(function() {
    $("#draggable_availability, #draggable-nonvalid").draggable();
    $("#droppable_availability").droppable({
      accept: "#draggable_availability",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        showquiz4();
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").find("p").html("Correct!");
      }
    });
  });
}

function dragItem_order() {
  $(function() {
    $("#draggable_order, #draggable-nonvalid").draggable();
    $("#droppable_order").droppable({
      accept: "#draggable_order",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        showquiz5();
        $(this)
          .addClass("ui-state-highlight").find("p").html("Correct!");
      }
    });
  });

}

function tabulateAnswers() {
  // initialize variables for each choice's score
  // If you add more choices and outcomes, you must add another variable here.
  var c1score = 0;
  var c2score = 0;
  var c3score = 0;
  var c4score = 0;

  // get a list of the radio inputs on the page
  var choices = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  // loop through all the radio inputs
  for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    // if the radio is checked..
    if (choices[i].checked) {
      // add 1 to that choice's score
      if (choices[i].value == 'c1') {
        c1score = c1score + 1;
      }
      if (choices[i].value == 'c2') {
        c2score = c2score + 1;
      }
      if (choices[i].value == 'c3') {
        c3score = c3score + 1;
      }
      if (choices[i].value == 'c4') {
        c4score = c4score + 1;
      }
      // If you add more choices and outcomes, you must add another if statement below.
    }
  }

  // Find out which choice got the highest score.
  // If you add more choices and outcomes, you must add the variable here.
  var maxscore = Math.max(c1score, c2score, c3score, c4score);

  // Display answer corresponding to that choice
  var answerbox = document.getElementById('answer');
  if (c1score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the first choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "You are correct"
  }
  if (c2score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the second choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "The correct answer is stvsp@am.sony.com"
  }
  if (c3score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the third choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "The correct answer is stvsp@am.sony.com"
  }
  if (c4score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the fourth choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "The correct answer is stvsp@am.sony.com"
  }
  // If you add more choices, you must add another response below.
}

// program the reset button
function resetAnswer() {
  var answerbox = document.getElementById('answer');
  answerbox.innerHTML = "Your result will show up here!";
}

function showquiz() {
  var e = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  e.style.display = "block";
}


function tabulateAnswers2() {
  // initialize variables for each choice's score
  // If you add more choices and outcomes, you must add another variable here.
  var c1score = 0;
  var c2score = 0;
  var c3score = 0;
  var c4score = 0;

  // get a list of the radio inputs on the page
  var choices = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  // loop through all the radio inputs
  for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    // if the radio is checked..
    if (choices[i].checked) {
      // add 1 to that choice's score
      if (choices[i].value == 'c1') {
        c1score = c1score + 1;
      }
      if (choices[i].value == 'c2') {
        c2score = c2score + 1;
      }
      if (choices[i].value == 'c3') {
        c3score = c3score + 1;
      }
      if (choices[i].value == 'c4') {
        c4score = c4score + 1;
      }
      // If you add more choices and outcomes, you must add another if statement below.
    }
  }

  // Find out which choice got the highest score.
  // If you add more choices and outcomes, you must add the variable here.
  var maxscore = Math.max(c1score, c2score, c3score, c4score);

  // Display answer corresponding to that choice
  var answerbox = document.getElementById('answer2');
  if (c1score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the first choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "The correct answer is 24 - 48 hours"
  }
  if (c2score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the second choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "The correct answer is 24 - 48 hours"
  }
  if (c3score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the third choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "The correct answer is 24 - 48 hours"
  }
  if (c4score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the fourth choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "You are correct"
  }
  // If you add more choices, you must add another response below.
}

// program the reset button
function resetAnswer2() {
  var answerbox = document.getElementById('answer2');
  answerbox.innerHTML = "Your result will show up here!";
}

function showquiz2() {
  var b = document.getElementById('wrapper2');
  b.style.display = "block";
}

function tabulateAnswers3() {
  // initialize variables for each choice's score
  // If you add more choices and outcomes, you must add another variable here.
  var c1score = 0;
  var c2score = 0;
  var c3score = 0;
  var c4score = 0;

  // get a list of the radio inputs on the page
  var choices = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  // loop through all the radio inputs
  for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    // if the radio is checked..
    if (choices[i].checked) {
      // add 1 to that choice's score
      if (choices[i].value == 'c1') {
        c1score = c1score + 1;
      }
      if (choices[i].value == 'c2') {
        c2score = c2score + 1;
      }
      if (choices[i].value == 'c3') {
        c3score = c3score + 1;
      }
      if (choices[i].value == 'c4') {
        c4score = c4score + 1;
      }
      // If you add more choices and outcomes, you must add another if statement below.
    }
  }

  // Find out which choice got the highest score.
  // If you add more choices and outcomes, you must add the variable here.
  var maxscore = Math.max(c1score, c2score, c3score, c4score);

  // Display answer corresponding to that choice
  var answerbox = document.getElementById('answer3');
  if (c1score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the first choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "Customer will get a brand new replacement"
  }
  if (c2score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the second choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "You are correct"
  }
  if (c3score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the third choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "Customer will get a brand new replacement"
  }
  if (c4score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the fourth choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "Customer will get a brand new replacement"
  }
  // If you add more choices, you must add another response below.
}

// program the reset button
function resetAnswer3() {
  var answerbox = document.getElementById('answer3');
  answerbox.innerHTML = "Your result will show up here!";
}

function showquiz3() {
  var b = document.getElementById('wrapper3');
  b.style.display = "block";
}

function tabulateAnswers4() {
  // initialize variables for each choice's score
  // If you add more choices and outcomes, you must add another variable here.
  var c1score = 0;
  var c2score = 0;
  var c3score = 0;
  var c4score = 0;

  // get a list of the radio inputs on the page
  var choices = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  // loop through all the radio inputs
  for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    // if the radio is checked..
    if (choices[i].checked) {
      // add 1 to that choice's score
      if (choices[i].value == 'c1') {
        c1score = c1score + 1;
      }
      if (choices[i].value == 'c2') {
        c2score = c2score + 1;
      }
      if (choices[i].value == 'c3') {
        c3score = c3score + 1;
      }
      if (choices[i].value == 'c4') {
        c4score = c4score + 1;
      }
      // If you add more choices and outcomes, you must add another if statement below.
    }
  }

  // Find out which choice got the highest score.
  // If you add more choices and outcomes, you must add the variable here.
  var maxscore = Math.max(c1score, c2score, c3score, c4score);

  // Display answer corresponding to that choice
  var answerbox = document.getElementById('answer4');
  if (c1score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the first choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "Customer will get a brand new replacement"
  }
  if (c2score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the second choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "You are correct"
  }
  if (c3score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the third choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "Customer will get a brand new replacement"
  }
  if (c4score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the fourth choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "Customer will get a brand new replacement"
  }
  // If you add more choices, you must add another response below.
}

// program the reset button
function resetAnswer4() {
  var answerbox = document.getElementById('answer4');
  answerbox.innerHTML = "Your result will show up here!";
}

function showquiz4() {
  var b = document.getElementById('wrapper4');
  b.style.display = "block";
}

function tabulateAnswers5() {
  // initialize variables for each choice's score
  // If you add more choices and outcomes, you must add another variable here.
  var c1score = 0;
  var c2score = 0;
  var c3score = 0;
  var c4score = 0;

  // get a list of the radio inputs on the page
  var choices = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  // loop through all the radio inputs
  for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    // if the radio is checked..
    if (choices[i].checked) {
      // add 1 to that choice's score
      if (choices[i].value == 'c1') {
        c1score = c1score + 1;
      }
      if (choices[i].value == 'c2') {
        c2score = c2score + 1;
      }
      if (choices[i].value == 'c3') {
        c3score = c3score + 1;
      }
      if (choices[i].value == 'c4') {
        c4score = c4score + 1;
      }
      // If you add more choices and outcomes, you must add another if statement below.
    }
  }

  // Find out which choice got the highest score.
  // If you add more choices and outcomes, you must add the variable here.
  var maxscore = Math.max(c1score, c2score, c3score, c4score);

  // Display answer corresponding to that choice
  var answerbox = document.getElementById('answer4');
  if (c1score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the first choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "Customer will get a brand new replacement"
  }
  if (c2score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the second choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "You are correct"
  }
  if (c3score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the third choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "Customer will get a brand new replacement"
  }
  if (c4score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the fourth choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "Customer will get a brand new replacement"
  }
  // If you add more choices, you must add another response below.
}

// program the reset button
function resetAnswer5() {
  var answerbox = document.getElementById('answer5');
  answerbox.innerHTML = "Your result will show up here!";
}

function showquiz5() {
  var b = document.getElementById('wrapper5');
  b.style.display = "block";
}

function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");


}

dragItem_ts();
dragItem_email();
dragItem_validation();
dragItem_availability();
dragItem_order();
```

```css
#droppable_ts,
#droppable_email,
#droppable_validation,
#droppable_availability,
#droppable_order,
#droppable_quality,
#droppable_shipment,
#droppable_delivery {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

#draggable_ts,
#draggable_email,
#draggable_validation,
#draggable_availability,
#draggable_order {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  z-index: 4;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

#wrapper,
#wrapper2,
#wrapper3,
#wrapper4,
#wrapper5 {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: none;
}

input {
  margin: 5px 10px;
}

button {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #333;
}

#submit {
  background: green;
}

#reset {
  background: red;
}

#answer {
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}

#draggable_container {
  background-color: blue;
}

.ui-widget-content {
  background-color: #99ff66;
  margin: auto;
  width: 12.5%;
}

.draggable_container_inner {
  heigth: 100px;
  width: 12.5%;
  float: left;
}

.draggable_container {
  width: 1400px;
}

#droppable_ts {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#droppable_email {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* The actual popup */

#droppable_ts .popuptextTs {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#droppable_email .popuptextEmail {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Popup arrow */

#droppable_ts.popuptextTs::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

#droppable_email.popuptextEmail::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}


/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */

#droppable_ts .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animatitsadeIn 1s;
}

#droppable_email .show2 {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animatitsadeIn 1s;
}


/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src=javascript/functions.js>
</script>
<div id="draggable_container">
  <div class="draggable_container_inner">
    <div id="draggable_ts" class="ui-widget-content">
      <img src="images/ts_image02.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="draggable_container_inner">
    <div id="draggable_email" class="ui-widget-content">
      <img src="images/email_logo.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="draggable_container_inner">
    <div id="draggable_validation" class="ui-widget-content">
      <img src="images/validation_logo.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="draggable_container_inner">
    <div id="draggable_availability" class="ui-widget-content">
      <img src="images/availability_logo.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="draggable_container_inner">
    <div id="draggable_order" class="ui-widget-content">
      <img src="images/order_logo.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="draggable_container_inner">
    <div id="draggable_email" class="ui-widget-content">
      <img src="images/quality_logo.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="draggable_container_inner">
    <div id="draggable_email" class="ui-widget-content">
      <img src="images/shipment_logo.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="draggable_container_inner">
    <div id="draggable_email" class="ui-widget-content">
      <img src="images/delivered_logo.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="droppable_container">
  <div id="droppable_ts" class="ui-widget-header" onclick="myFunction()">
    <span class="popuptextTs" id="myPopup">This step is where the  level 1 support does troubleshooting</span>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="droppable_email" class="ui-widget-header" onclick="myFunction2()">
    <span class="popuptextEmail" id="myPopup">This step is where the customer needs to send the email for verification</span>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="droppable_validation" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="droppable_availability" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="droppable_quality" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="droppable_shipment" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="droppable_delivery" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1>What is the email address that the customer should send them to?</h1>
  <form id="quiz">
    <!-- Question 1 -->
    <!-- Here are the choices for the first question. Each input tag must have the same name. For this question, the name is q1. -->
    <!-- The value is which answer the choice corresponds to. -->
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c1">
      stvsp@am.com
    </label><br />
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c2">
      svtsp@am.com
    </label><br />
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c3">
      mydocs@am.com
    </label><br />
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c4">
      docs@am.com
    </label><br />
    <button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="tabulateAnswers()">Submit Your Answers</button>
    <button type="reset" id="reset" onclick="resetAnswer()">Reset</button>
  </form>
  <div id="answer">Your result will show up here!</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper2">
  <h1>What is the TAT for validating the pictures and POP?</h1>
  <form id="quiz">
    <!-- Question 1 -->
    <!-- Here are the choices for the first question. Each input tag must have the same name. For this question, the name is q1. -->
    <!-- The value is which answer the choice corresponds to. -->
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c1">
      24 hours
    </label><br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c2">
      6 hours
    </label><br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c3">
      72 hours
    </label><br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c4">
      24 - 48 hours
    </label><br />
    <button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="tabulateAnswers2()">Submit Your Answers</button>
    <button type="reset" id="reset" onclick="resetAnswer2()">Reset</button>
  </form>
  <div id="answer2">Your result will show up here!</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper3">
  <h1>What will the customer get if the original unit is within 90 days from DOP?</h1>
  <form id="quiz">
    <!-- Question 1 -->
    <!-- Here are the choices for the first question. Each input tag must have the same name. For this question, the name is q1. -->
    <!-- The value is which answer the choice corresponds to. -->
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c1">
      Refurbished Unit
    </label><br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c2">
      Brand New Replacement Unit
    </label><br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c3">
      Defective Unit
    </label><br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c4">
      Refund
    </label><br />
    <button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="tabulateAnswers3()">Submit Your Answers</button>
    <button type="reset" id="reset" onclick="resetAnswer3()">Reset</button>
  </form>
  <div id="answer3">Your result will show up here!</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper4">
  <h1>A B stock unit undergoes a different quality check from that of A stock. True or false?</h1>
  <form id="quiz">
    <!-- Question 1 -->
    <!-- Here are the choices for the first question. Each input tag must have the same name. For this question, the name is q1. -->
    <!-- The value is which answer the choice corresponds to. -->
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c1">
      True
    </label><br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c2">
      False
    </label><br />
    <label> 
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c3">
      N/A
    </label><br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c4">
      not sure
    </label><br />
    <button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="tabulateAnswers4()">Submit Your Answers</button>
    <button type="reset" id="reset" onclick="resetAnswer4()">Reset</button>
  </form>
  <div id="answer4">Your result will show up here!</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper5">
  <h1>A B stock unit undergoes a different quality check from that of A stock. True or false?</h1>
  <form id="quiz">
    <!-- Question 1 -->
    <!-- Here are the choices for the first question. Each input tag must have the same name. For this question, the name is q1. -->
    <!-- The value is which answer the choice corresponds to. -->
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c1">
      True
    </label><br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c2">
      False
    </label><br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c3">
      N/A
    </label><br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c4">
      not sure
    </label>
      <br />
    <button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="tabulateAnswers5()">Submit Your Answers</button>
    <button type="reset" id="reset" onclick="resetAnswer5()">Reset</button>
  </form>
  <div id="answer5">Your result will show up here!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change your button*s* from `<button type="submit"` to `<button type="button"`.  As they are `type='submit'`, it's POSTing the form to the server, which you're describing is not what you want it to do at this time.  Alternatively, add a `return false;` to the end of `function tabulateAnswers()` (and the others).

Comment: that helped, thank you, but I need to hide or remove the questionnaire once they click the submit, regardless if it is correct or not, any ideas? can I set it invisible through css?

Comment: I think I'll just put a close button on the side, thank you very much kind sir.

Comment: `$("#wrapper").hide();`

Comment: tried putting $("#wrapper").hide(); on the bottom part of the tabluateAnswer() but it does not seem to hide it after pressing the button.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. As of I found you already get the solution that you change the Button type to submit to the button.  Now comes next solution. You want to hide that div if the answer is correct.

1St solution is 
Old:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="tabulateAnswers4()">
```

New:

```
<button type="button" id="submit" onclick="tabulateAnswers4()">
```

Next, come to the 2nd solution to close the div after answer varified or clicked.

var answerbox = document.getElementById('answer2');

```
if (c1score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the first choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "The correct answer is 24 - 48 hours";
    $('wrapper').hide(3000);

  }
  if (c2score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the second choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "The correct answer is 24 - 48 hours";
    $('wrapper').hide(3000);
  }
  if (c3score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the third choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "The correct answer is 24 - 48 hours";
    $('wrapper').hide(3000);
  }
  if (c4score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the fourth choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
    answerbox.innerHTML = "You are correct";
    $('wrapper').hide(3000);
  }
  // If you add more choices, you must add another response below.
}
```

$('wrapper').hide(3000);
Time interval will help the user to see the answer for some interval of time. How much time you wish to give you can.

Refer this document for more details: 
http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: yeah I just found out that the return false prevents it from hiding the wrapper. Thank you for letting me know how to put time intervals on .hide functions. I'm learning new things everyday. Great community here

Comment: i am happy to help you.